# How does one package a python application that includes a gsettings schema with setuptools?

Tags: python, packaging, distutils, gsettings

I'm trying to use `setuptools` to package a python application that relies on gsettings for storing and retrieving user's preferences. However I have not used said tool before and I am unsure about what to do with the `setup.py` script in order to instruct it to install and compile the schema. It seems that the `data_files` argument can be used to specify additional files that will be installed in a specified directory, but how do make sure that `glib-compile-schemas` gets executed?

Comment: Copy-and-paste duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/790595/how-does-one-package-a-python-application-that-includes-a-gsettings-schema-with/1105262#1105262.